# Merge two iOS Project into one

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode-project

Is that possible to merge 2 projects into one.

I know it is possible to add all ressources (classes, storyboards, images) in one project, what I want to do is a more difficult :
1 big project own 2 others "subprojects" (with an app on it). 
This big project have a menu with 2 buttons (each button brings you to an app)

I think each project should have its own targets, own storyboards...

I that possible to do in IOS ?

Comment: are they different source code?

Comment: yes, 2 differents codes

Comment: why do you want to merge both? are they sharing common structure/Resources?

Comment: not at all, I just want to create 2 applications in one

Answer (score 2):

Each of the subprojects would need to be built as a library rather than an app.  The app would be created by the 'big project' and would create view controllers based on library objects when buttons were tapped.

The problem with just forcing two apps to exist under a third is that you'd have 3 `main` routines and app delegates (etc.) which would break linking.

Comment: Do you think the only good solution will be to add all ressources to the "big project" and  keep just one APPDelegate ?

Comment: That's one way.  The other would be to change the subprojects so that they each have a static library target (without app-level classes), then drag their Xcode projects into the top one and set up link dependencies.

Comment: Here's a reasonable starting point for the Xcode structure, in case you need it: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/12/sub-projects-in-xcode/